# MySQL Case Sensitive in Linux through Hibernate

Tags: mysql, linux, eclipse, hibernate

I moved my development environment in Eclipse from Windows to Debian. When I did that, I noticed that (just some) table names were not being found in MySQL when Hibernate was doing datamodel checks during initialization, due to case-sensitive issues. Two of the tables are still being searched by "Table_name" instead of "table_name". When it occours, Hibernate create new tables "Table_name" ignoring existent "table_name" ones. I read that it is due to a MySQL feature in case-sensitive O.S.

I've added `@Table(name="table_name")` statement in every model class, in order to avoid capitalization of table names by MySQL/Hibernate, and I reviewed all HQL queries in DAO Classes putting all table references to lower case, but I've not achieved success in either attempts.

What configuration am I missing in order to fix this behavior? Thanks.

Comment: Well, Alex, what happened?  Did you get it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a well known problem with MySQL because it creates an actual disk file per table.

Hibernate supposedly tries to overcome this problem specifically for MySQL by internally lowercasing all table names, but apparently this is not a bulletproof solution.

As far as I know there is nothing you can do besides making sure that consistent capitalization is used EVERYWHERE.  In other words, there is no magic configuration option that will do it for you.

If you use the "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" property to let hibernate create your database schema, then you should be fine, but if you are running hibernate on a pre-existing database then this is not enough, because you have to also make sure that the table was created in as 'table_name' and that any foreign key references also refer to it in as 'table_name'.  (So, the use of `@Table(name="table_name")` everywhere will not suffice.)

In either case, your database was created under windows, so even if you had hibernate create it, still it may have been created with whatever funny capitalization scheme you were using under windows, which means that you might want to throw away your database and re-create it.

Comment: thanks for responding. In fact, I've not looked after foreign keys. Maybe I'm going to do a dump of all my data and recreate database. On the other issue, sb here on stackoverflow adviced me to change to InteliJ. I've even installed it, but I'm late on my schedule, and I don't have time enough to go through another learning-curve. Linux actually made Eclipse (much) faster, I don't know exactly why. In Windows, Eclipse performance got terrible after an O.S. reinstalling. Maybe in my next project I would move to InteliJ so. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Sure, glad to be of help.  When you have a definite answer, please post your findings for the benefit of future generations of programmers.

Comment: It's necessary to take note on an important issue, which would be valuable to "future generations" of programmers: in my project, let's call it project A, there's a reference to another project, let's call project B, through Maven. When I made changes in project B, I forgot to update .jar file through Maven Install, and then update Project A reference. This way, during Project A building, old table names stored in an outdated .jar were being the source of the problem.